# Buffer Overflow C

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have been searching online for a few hours but still cannot figure out what is the vulnerability for below code. I have to produce a buffer overflow but I can't do that. If I have a payload that is bigger than 28, I go into the if statement and return false before function `fread` is executed in line 5.

Can somebody tell me how I can bypass this check to trigger the overflow?

```
package looks like this
+------------+------------+------------+
|tag = 1 byte|len = 1 byte|payload[len]|
+------------+------------+------------+
```

```
0. bool processNextPackage(void){
1.   char buf[32];
2.   if(!fread(buf, 2, 1, stdin){
3.     return false;
4.   }
5.   if(buf[1] > sizeof(buf)-3 || !fread(buf + 2, buf[1], 1, stdin)){
6.     return false;
7.   }
8.   buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0'
9.   return false;
10.}
```

Comment: not sure it's a vulnerability, but passing a value > 0x7F makes `buf[1]` negative.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, `char` is a signed type.

Comment: @NieDzejkob in most systems yes by default. Oh I think that's the issue.

Comment: I answered but deleted: my answer is probably wrong: if `buf[1]` is negative, then comparing to unsigned fails and we don't enter `fread`: "if the second byte of the payload is in range 0x80 .. 0xFF, that makes the value negative so it passes the test.": wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The implicit type promotion seems mostly by accident though. This is sloppily written code: `buf[1] > sizeof(buf)-3`. Should have been written as `(size_t)buf[1] > sizeof(buf)-3u` to demonstrate that the programmer has a clue about implicit promotions.

Comment: Seems like a waste of time to ponder such meaningless code in the first place. I suppose entering 0 won't do much good, causing the function to return before appending null termination. But the function returns false no matter what you do and it doesn't use the local scope buffer anywhere outside the function, so who cares.

Comment: @Lundin okay. But anyway `-1 > sizeof(buf)-3` tests as false here, so my hypothesis isn't valid. Yeah: my life isn't depending on it so as you say: "who cares" :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `-1 > sizeof(buf)-3` Will always evaluate to true (1).

Comment: @Lundin my bad. Yes. So the `fread` is never reached. And my answer is wrong :)

Comment: Anyway, I suppose it is C++ (not C) because of the `bool` return type, right?

Comment: @StephanLechner The C language has a bool type since the year 1999. Time to update your knowledge, perhaps.

Comment: even when i pass for example in buf[1] the value FF which means is -1 > sizeof(buf)-3 still i get true...why that?

Comment: I will edit my deleted answer to explain tgat. But to me there is no vulnerability in this code.

Comment: @Jet can you show the function caller and how the buffer is used/printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that `char` is `signed char` here (this is the most common but not all compilers do that)

The only possible vulnerability would be to try to pass a bigger length than the allowed max length. Here, we have a byte to do that.

This condition is the one which could be attacked:

```
if(buf[1] > sizeof(buf)-3 || !fread(buf + 2, buf[1], 1, stdin))
```

the short-circuit operator prevents entering in `fread` (and read too many bytes from the file) if `buf[1]` is too big.

But if the value is in range `0x80 .. 0xff`, that makes `buf[1]` *negative* because of (probably) signed `char`. That would be unexpected.

BUT it still doesn't pass the test because comparing negative to unsigned `sizeof(buf)-3` always makes the negative value the biggest.

Aside: `buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0'`: looks like we're nul terminating the string for `printf` display purposes. If buffer is too big, this isn't done (because we return earlier), and the code could crash when printing an unterminated string. So the buffer would have to be set to all zeroes before reading.

But apart from that, the code has no vulnerability I can see.

However, *if* it was written like this:

```
int sz = sizeof(buf)-3;
if(buf[1] > sz || !fread(buf + 2, buf[1], 1, stdin))
```

there would be a vulnerability since comparing negative to signed would pass to `fread`, and when `fread` is called, a negative value is passed as `size`, but `fread` expects unsigned:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

so it would have been possible that the value is converted as a positive (and too big) value: put `0xFF` in `buf[1]`, it becomes `-1` as signed char, but passed to `fread` it becomes a positive value, bigger than the buffer.

So, since the value is very big, it will read every byte of the file: you can inject malicious code there.

So to be sure that noone rewrites the code that way:

- use `unsigned char` for the `buf` variable to avoid strange integer/unsigned integer comparison effects.
- initialize buffer to all zeroes to avoid crash when using `printf` on non nul-terminated buffer.

Comment: For your answer to make sense, you need to address the fact that `char` has implementation-defined signedness. There is nothing preventing a compiler from making the default `char` type unsigned. It is not obvious that `0x80` etc will result in negative values.

Comment: @Jet thanks for accepting. Since I didn't find a real vulnerability (I think I've proven my point), are you sure there's one in that code?